# How to paused a video .avi in a beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, movie15

I'm creating a presentation with `beamer`, where in a frame I want to put a video `.avi` (I would press `play` and `pause` from the frame). I have to discuss this presentation, so I need that the video is embedded in the `pdf` and that it can also be seen on other devices.
I tried in this way, with the `movie15` package:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[italian,english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{movie15}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Evolutionary Dynamics of the Network}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\includemovie[poster,text={\small(Loading Video...)}]{6cm}{6cm}{timelapse_(fps_6000).avi}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The video is good but there is no way to pause after it started and maybe I will need to do it. From the manual of `movie15` package I see that there is the option `autopause`, that switching to the next frame while the video runs this is paused, but I need to pause it manually, like a normal video. Someone has advice?
Another thing, you believe that if via a USB key, I open the `pdf` in the device which I will have to discuss the presentation, the video will be present anyway?

Comment: Did you try the letters `p`, `l` and space bar? I don't remember them but try your keyboard or put a cat on it. It will find it instantly.

Comment: Please note: for new documents you should use [`media9`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/media9), which supersedes `movie15`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If videos are inserted using the `media9` package, they can easily be **paused by pressing the mouse button** over them. They continue playing after releasing the mouse button again. If they should pause for a longer time, move the mouse pointer out of the video area while keeping the mouse button pressed.

You need to convert your video to MP4/h264 for use with `media9`. You can do that [online](http://video.online-convert.com/convert-to-mp4), or using [`ffmpeg` or `avconv`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/media9/doc/media9.pdf#page=2).

Minimal example using your video converted to `timelapse.mp4`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{media9}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Evolutionary Dynamics of the Network}

\includemedia[
  width=6cm,height=6cm,
  addresource=timelapse.mp4,
  transparent, %transparent player background
  activate=pageopen,
  flashvars={
    source=timelapse.mp4
   &scaleMode=letterbox % best choice if the video doesn't fit exactly into the
                        % 6x6cm^2 area set-up by the width and height options
  }
]{}{VPlayer.swf}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Additionally, you may insert a `\mediabutton` to play/pause the video, but this is not really necessary. See the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/media9/doc/media9.pdf) for that.

Comment: AlexG the code is fine but there are still two things that lead me to use `movie15` and not `media9`: the first is that with `media9` with converting in `.mp4` a top piece of the video is cut, the second is that with the presentation seems to have problems with the colors, some frames have the green of the theme that I have chosen while in others the green becomes clearly darker and this also applies to colors of the graphs that I presented.

Comment: @GiacomoRosaspina Interesting. Which A-Reader version on which platform are you using?

Comment: I solve the first problem, I've just set the size video as original in my converter. For the second problem, I've win7 and Adobe Reader X.

Comment: @GiacomoRosaspina What happens if you use package option `noplaybutton` ?

Comment: Looks great, the green of the theme is maintained in all the frames. Maybe I write something in the box of the video, so initially is not white and empty.

Comment: @GiacomoRosaspina I will have to investigate this further. Thank you for reporting!

Answer (score 1):

I got some advice from professor that worked on `movie15`.

On `\includemovie` section, I added `mouse=true` to give me the option of pausing when clicking on the picture and resuming when clicking outside of the picture.

Hope this helps someone.